# Accessing nested data with key/value pairs in array

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with schema

```
root
|-- properties: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

An example of 3 rows from the df appears as:

```json
[]

[{"key":"id", "value":"as143"},
  {"key":"user", "value":"John Doe"},
  {"key":"email", "value":"j.doe@gmail.com"},
  {"key":"location", "value":"KY, USA"}]

[{"key":"id", "value":"bd143"},
  {"key":"user", "value":"Adam Smith"},
  {"key":"email", "value":"a.smith@gmail.com"}]
```

So each new user is in a new row in the df. The amount of data in each row can be different with null values being allowed.

I would like to make a new df such that each key would be the new column name and the values in the column would be all the corresponding values of that key. For example, I would have a column titled 'user' and each row would have a different user name.

I have tried to access the sub-fields using  this code but I get an error.

```
keys = table.select('properties.key').distinct().collect()[0][0]
table.withColumn('value', split(table.properties.value, ',')).
    select(col('value'[0].alias(keys[0]),
    select(col('value'[1].alias(keys[1]),
    select(col('value'[2].alias(keys[2]),
    select(col('value'[3].alias(keys[3])).display()
```

I have also tried to create a key, value map because I need to do these for other columns in the dataframe and for some of them, it is hard to tell have many key/value pairs there are since they are allowed to be null values so I may use `pyspark.sql.functions.from_json`.

I feel this is the preferred way, however, I have not had success with that either. I have not been able to convert to a map and I think it is because rather than having `"key":"value"` pairs I have `"key": "key 1",  "value": "value 1", "key": "key 2",  "value": "value 2", "key": "key 3",  "value": "value 3"`, etc all in the same row.

This is the code I used:

```
table.withColumn('properties', from_json(table.properties, MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
```

and I get the error:

> cannot resolve 'entries' due to data type mismatch: argument 1
> requires string type, however 'table.properties' is of
> array<struct<key:string, value:string>> type.

I am not exactly sure how to go about converting an array type like this to a map.

Comment: Can the array `properties` contain multiple users? If so, can you show example? I think this can be done using some pivot after exploding the array but It's not clear on how you can have same key.

Comment: I have edited my question so it shows 3 rows. Each row in the actual data frame has anywhere from 0 to 4 key:value pairs. table.properties.key gives me a list of my keys and table.properties.value gives a list of the corresponding values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your input dataframe:

```
data = '[{"properties":[]},{"properties":[{"key":"id","value":"as143"},{"key":"user","value":"John Doe"},{"key":"email","value":"j.doe@gmail.com"},{"key":"location","value":"KY, USA"}]},{"properties":[{"key":"id","value":"bd143"},{"key":"user","value":"Adam Smith"},{"key":"email","value":"a.smith@gmail.com"}]}]'
table = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([data]))
```

Your column `properties` is of type array of structs, that's why you get data mismatch error when you try to use `from_json` function. You can simply explode expand the array to get 2 columns `key` and `value` like this:

```
table.selectExpr("inline(properties)").show()

#+--------+-----------------+
#|     key|            value|
#+--------+-----------------+
#|      id|            as143|
#|    user|         John Doe|
#|   email|  j.doe@gmail.com|
#|location|          KY, USA|
#|      id|            bd143|
#|    user|       Adam Smith|
#|   email|a.smith@gmail.com|
#+--------+-----------------+
```

That said, now what you want is to [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html) the column `key`. In order to use pivot, we need some column `ID` on which to groupby, if you don't have this column, you can assign a `row_id` using `monotonically_increasing_id` function before exploding the array:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = table.withColumn("row_id", F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .selectExpr("row_id", "inline(properties)") \
    .groupBy("row_id").pivot("key").agg(F.first("value")).drop("row_id")

result.show()

#+-----------------+-----+--------+----------+
#|            email|   id|location|      user|
#+-----------------+-----+--------+----------+
#|  j.doe@gmail.com|as143| KY, USA|  John Doe|
#|a.smith@gmail.com|bd143|    null|Adam Smith|
#+-----------------+-----+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just couldn't figure this out before. I really appreciate it!